# Kernel upgrade on Debian 8.7 VPS to get virtualbox to run

Tags: debian, kernel, virtualbox, upgrade

I am trying to get virtualbox run on my Debian 8.7 (64 bit architecture) box.

On submitting the vboxconfig command:

```
/sbin/vboxconfig
```

I get the following response:

```
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /lib/modules/3.16.0-042stab116.1/kernel
This system is not currently set up to build kernel modules (system extensions).
Running the following commands should set the system up correctly:

  apt-get install -headers-3.16.0-042stab116.1
(The last command may fail if your system is not fully updated.)
  apt-get install -headers
vboxdrv.sh: failed: Look at /var/log/vbox-install.log to find out what went wrong.
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /lib/modules/3.16.0-042stab116.1/kernel
This system is not currently set up to build kernel modules (system extensions).
Running the following commands should set the system up correctly:

  apt-get install -headers-3.16.0-042stab116.1
(The last command may fail if your system is not fully updated.)
  apt-get install -headers

There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run
  /sbin/vboxconfig
```

Following the suggestion I started the installation of the header files (after rectifying the typo with the dash in front of the package name headers-3.16.0-042stab116.1):

```
apt-get install headers-3.16.0-042stab116.1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package headers-3.16.0-042stab116.1
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'headers-3.16.0-042stab116.1'
```

My sources.list reads as follows:

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie main contrib non-free
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org jessie/updates main contrib non-free
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian jessie contrib
```

I assume that the package containing headers-3.16.0-042stab116.1 is not avalaible in the repos (any more). Therefore my approach would be trying to update the kernel accorrdingly so that I can install newer headers.

My questions now: this is a VPS, not a desktop machine.

Will I be able to do a kernel update on such a server?
And if so: how do I find out which one would be the appropriate kernel image to be installed (apt-cache search linux-image provides an awful lot of results)?

Cheers

Comment: No VPS host will allow users to run their VM for many reasons, mainly for performance reasons.  It would clog up their host.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the package should be linux-headers, not just headers.

Answer (score 0):

To set up the correct build environment in Debian, use:

`apt install module-assistant
m-a prepare`

Answer (score 0):

```
apt install linux-headers-amd64  build-essential dkms
```